# Error in C# get enumerator definition

Tags: c#, struct, ienumerable

I have a structure in my code as below

```
public struct ColumnSpec
{
    public string specName;
    public string delimiters;
    public string commentChars;
    public int titleLines;
    public Column[] Columns;
    public SymbolFile testrangefile;

    public ColumnSpec(bool input)
    {
        specName = null;
        delimiters = null;
        commentChars = null;
        titleLines = 0;
        Columns = new Column[3];
        Columns[0] = new Column();
        Columns[1] = new Column();
        Columns[2] = new Column();
        testrangefile = new SymbolFile();
    }
}
```

Now i have an instance of this struct 
ColumnSpec computed;

When i used this in the below loop i am getting an error saying ColumnSpec  does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
foreach (string element in computed)
{

}
```

Can u help resolving the error.

Comment: What are you trying to enumerate?

Comment: I gather `computed` is of Type `ColumnSpec`. In this case `ColumnSpec` would need to implement IEnumerable to be able to loop on the type.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when doing `foreach (string element in computed)`?

Comment: I wish to make a string using all the variable values in the struct ( ColumnSpec computed; )

Comment: You can't enumerate over computed. You need to enumerate over computed.Columns. e.g. `foreach(var element in computed.Columns)`

Comment: What should i do if i need to enumerate in the below order

Comment: specName,delimiters ,Columns[0],Columns[1],Columns[2],testrangefile.fname,testrangefile.sname (test range file is an instance of a struct)

Comment: @user3048305 - Then you should implement a method inside the [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0taef578.aspx) to do exactly that. If you just want one big string to represent the content, then you might want to override [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173154.aspx).

Comment: this is wat i want inside the foreach loop 
    foreach (var element in computed)
    {
    messagebox.show ("......"+element+"......"); 
    }
and the element order is mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: From the top of my head: `public IEnumerable<string> GetValues() { yield return specName; yield return delimiters; yield return Columns[0]; yield return Columns[1]; yield return Columns[2]; yield return testrangefile.fname; yield return youGetThePicture; }`. All this as a method inside the struct. Now you can `foreach (string element in computed.GetValues()) { // do stuff }`.

Answer (score 1):

For something to have an enumerator it needs to implement `IEnumerable` which your struct does not

Comment: Note: It doesn't need to implement `IEnumerable` `GetEnumerator` method is enough

Comment: I am new to IEnumerable . how shd i implement Ienumerable in this case to resolve this error.

Comment: @user3048305 You should tell us what you need in foreach to be enumerated?

Comment: I need to enumerate ( ColumnSpec computed; ) .

Answer (score 1):

Enumerators in C# don't do what you think they do. They're used to go over collections of items, like arrays, lists or other objects that implement the `IEnumerable` interface, either explicitly or implicitly. They're not used to iterate over the fields of a struct.

There are two ways of doing what you want. The first is to override the `ToString` method in your `ColumnSpec` struct. `ToString()` is a standard method shared by all types in .NET, and provides the print-out logic for your type. Since it's implemented inside your code, you can reference your fields explicitly and create a single string from them all.

If you're looking for a generic solution after all, you'll have to look into [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which lets you examine the fields and properties of a struct at runtime, and has similar syntax to what you've tried:

```
ColumnSpec computed; // your instance.
Type myType = typeof(ColumnSpec); The reflected Type of ColumnSpec.
string combinedString = "";
foreach (FieldInfo field in myType.GetFields()) // this enumerates all public fields.
{
    if (field.FieldType == typeof(string)) // only for strings
    {
        string fieldValue = field.GetValue(computed); // extract the value.
        combinedString += fieldValue;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example, but it should get you started with Reflection. A more comprehensive solution will have you drill down deeper, using reflection, into the array of `Column` objects, extracting the data from them as well.

A third option, as mentioned in the comments by @Corak, will allow you to expose your values as an enumerator, maintaining their order, but without reflection, by adding the following method to your struct:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetElements()
{
    yield return specName;
    yield return delimiters;
    . . . // you get the idea.
    foreach (Column column in Columns)
    {
        yield return column.Name;
    }
    yield return testrangefile.Filename;
}
```

This will expose an IEnumerable of strings, while explicitly [`yield`ing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) allows you to fill this enumerable lazily, in the order you want. You can then call it like this:

```
foreach (string element in computed.GetElements())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an enumerator. You get what you want by adding a `ToString()` to `ColumnSpec`

```
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}",
    specName,
    delimiters,
    Columns[0],
    Columns[1],
    Columns[2],
    testrangefile.fname,
    testrangefile.sname);
  }
```